# RequireJS recursive module loading

Tags: module, requirejs

I have 2 modules A and B. Also I have 3 libs L1, L2 and L3.

**Module A**:

```
define(
    ['L1', 'L2'],
    function (L1, L2) { ... }
);
```

**Module B**:

```
define(
    ['A', 'L3'],
    function (A, L3) { ... }
);
```

**Is i'm right that module B already have L1 and L2 libs in scope or I must reinclude these libs?**

*Module B*:

```
define(
    ['A', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3'],
    function (A, L1, L2, L3) { ... }
);
```

Comment: why is this -1? I had the same question

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use those libs in `Modulue B` you have to explicitly name them in your definition.

```
define(['A', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3'], function (A, L1, L2, L3) {

    // ...
});
```

If you don't want to use them this will be okay:

```
define(['A', 'L3'], function (A, L3) {

    // L1 undefined here
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that L1 is undefined here?

Comment: yes, you can use `A` without problems, it has it's own references to `L1` etc.. but `L1` will be undefined in the scope of your `define`-function

Comment: Comment by Jasmine Hegman: L1 undefined, although its possible A could provide a means to access it (its loaded as a dependency of A which is a dependency of this script alongide L3).